# How to implement workflowcore for registration page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, workflow

I need to create a registration page in xamarin.forms by implementing workflowcore.

I installed workflowcore nuget using the below link,

https://workflow-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

At first step, i created the login page. When username and password is entered , signin button is clicked and it will display a alert box. If ok is clicked in alertbox, it will move on to next page or it will return back to login page.

And Second step is signup page if not login.

The firststep is working fine and it is not executing second step.

Workflow:

```
    public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder<object> builder)
    {
        builder
           .StartWith<LoginStep>()              
           .Then<SignUpStep>();         
    }
```

SignUp step:

```
   public class SignUpStep: StepBody
   {
    public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
    {

        App.GlobalNavigationProperty.PushAsync(new SignUpPage());
        return ExecutionResult.Next();
    }
   }
```

Does anyone know how to implement workflowcore in xamarin.forms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, is there occurs error log when app running ?

Comment: No error log. nextstep is not executing. in UI it is not visible

Comment: Okey , that means `SignUpStep` not be executed .Or you can use breakpoint to check executing to which step .